# Email quota restricted to 50 emails for app script [google-apps-script]

Tags: api, google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace, mailmerge

I have contacted Google Support and they have directed me here

I'm using a Mail Merge AppScript which can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/mail-merge)

Code can be [found here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/solutions/tree/master/mail-merge)

It says that it complies with Google's daily quotas for sending mail but I'm only able to send 50 emails per 24-hours with a G Suite Basic account which has a listed quota of 1,500 recipients per day (however the Google support colleagues said it's 2,000).

I am sending to individual people and Bcc'ing a different email to each of them (the Bcc email is the same email for each unique recipient), which, I believe only counts towards 1 of my daily allowance as the quota is for unique email recipients, right?

Anyway, I send using the mail merge script and it works for 50 people and then says the limit has been reached yet I'm able to send regular, manual emails from mail.google.com which suggests the limit for my entire G Suite Basic account has ***not*** been reached but instead is something on the side of the app code?

Google Support linked me here and said that my quota for scrips could be increased by asking... It seemed a bit weird to me but I'm going along with what I've been told

Thanks for any help or suggestions :-)

Kai

Comment: Can you share the code. you might be sending the mails to quickly. Also, the actual mail.google.com does not count agains api quota.

Comment: Code can be found here: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/solutions/tree/master/mail-merge :) thanks for your reply

Comment: Did you miss the `*`? New gsuite accounts are limited. [`*Note: Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer users. For more information, see the Help Center page on sending limits.`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#note1)

Comment: Can you update on your situation, what error message did you get? How is the implementation on your side? Have you checked if you are on the first billing cycle as TheMaster said?